# What architecture is best for creating a serverless aws service?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I need to implement an AWS service used to store back-up data from devices. 
Devices are identified via ids. Service consists of 3 endpoints:

1. Save device backup.
2. Get device backup.
3. Get latest device backup time.

Backup: binary data, from 10kb up to 1mb

### Load examples

1. 100к saved backups per day. 2k restored backups per day.
2. Take p1 and multiply by 100

[I came up with 2 architectures.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sEthNBCw9uE2MPEXoMi0_5kJobqO_irn/view?usp=sharing)

1. Which architecture is better to choose or build a new one?
2. Can I combine the gateway api into one or do I need a separate API for each request?
3. Can I merge lambda into one or do I need a separate action for each action?

Comment: Unless you plan on keeping the drive up forever it is much better to use another way (a screenshot) to embed the architectures into the question. This will allow this question to be useful long after the drive diagrams are gone. Happy Posting !

Comment: Will lambda and the gateway api withstand such loads?

backup - binary data, from 10kb up to 1mb

## Load examples
1. 100к saved backups per day. 2k restored backups per day.
2. Take p1 and multiply by 100

Answer (score 0):

A device backup would consist of two elements:

- The backup **data**: Best stored in Amazon S3
- **Metadata** about the backup (user, timestamp, pointer to backup data): Best stored in some type of database, such as DynamoDB

The processes would then be:

- **Saving backup:** Send backup data via API Gateway to Lambda. The Lambda function would save the data in Amazon S3 and add an entry to the DynamoDB database, returning a reference to the backup entry in the database.
- **Retrieving backup:** Send request via API Gateway to Lambda. The Lambda function uses the metadata in DynamoDB to determine which backup to serve, then creates an **Amazon S3 pre-signed URL** and returns the URL to the device. The device then **retrieves the backup directly from the S3 bucket**.
- **Listing backups:** Send request via API Gateway to Lambda. The Lambda function uses the metadata in DynamoDB to retrieve a list of backups (or just the latest backup), then returns the values.

It would be cleaner to use a separate Lambda function for each type of request (save, retrieve, list). These would be triggered via different paths within API Gateway.

Comment: Will lambda and the gateway api withstand such loads? backup - binary data, from 10kb up to 1mb ## Load examples 1. 100к saved backups per day. 2k restored backups per day. 2. Take p1 and multiply by 100

Comment: I would also use a presigned S3 url for uploads. API Gateway and Lambda can definitely scale to your load. The main factors are going to be: (1) cost, (2) latency, and (3) fault tolerance. By using a presigned url for uploads, you remove 2 points of failure from the upload path, and allow the client to retry failed uploads without incurring additional Lambda invocations. Depending on what metadata is stored and how it needs to be retrieved, you can also remove the Dynamo dependency by storing metadata in a combination of key prefix and S3 metadata.